# Trouble creating venn diagram with data

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been given data to insert into a venn diagram but I am having trouble doing so. The diagram is needed to aid finding other data. The data is given explaining which workers work on which floor in a building. The diagram would obviously consists of a 3 circle diagram, one for each floor. Here is the data I am given;

A survey was created to ask 60 workers which floor in the 3-storey building they had cause to work on.
The results were collated:

- 29 worked on the ground floor
- 10 worked on the second, first and ground floor
- 33 worked on the first floor
- 12 worked ONLY on ground and first floor
- 6 worked ONLY on the second floor
- 2 worked ONLY on the second and ground floor
- 1 worked ONLY on the second and first floor

Obviously I tried taking the data and inserting in onto the diagram as follows, but when trying to work out how many workers were on each floor I am given inaccurate results meaning my diagram is wrong.

[image]

Would someone be able to create a venn diagram out of the data given?

**EDIT**

After taking in some of the answers I have created the following diagram, is it possible that the number of workers doesn't have to add up to 60?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show us your efforts if so.

Comment: Yes, edited post.

Comment: Perhaps the remaining workers go on the *outside* (aka, the "complement") of the three circles, because they don't actually work in the building?

Answer (score 2):

When it says for instance, $29$ worked on the ground floor, this means your total for all $4$ Venn-diagram regions making up Ground floor should total to $29$.  This means that the region that is ground floor only should be $29-24=5$ (since there are $24$ in the other three regions of ground floor).  I think your regions of overlap between various sets are correct.  It's just the regions that are in only one set that need adjusting.  (And not necessarily all of those).

Answer (score 0):

We can check the data correctness by solving the problem in another way.
We can divide workers in $7$ non-intersecting sets: $W_G, W_1, W_2, W_{G1}, W_{G2}, W_{12}, W_{G12}$ where index means floors visited by set members and correspondently $w_k = |W_k|$.
Then
$$w_G + w_{G1} + w_{G2} + w_{G12} = 29$$
$$w_{G12} = 10$$
$$w_1 + w_{G1} + w_{12} + w_{12G} = 33$$
$$w_{G1} = 12$$
$$w_2 = 6$$
$$w_{G2} = 2$$
$$w_{12} = 1$$

We can simply find from here that $(w_G, w_1, w_2, w_{G1}, w_{G2}, w_{12}, w_{G12}) = (5,9,6,12,2,1,10)$, so the sum is $45$, not $60$.